# How do I assert the result is an email in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, email, testing, phpunit

I would like to be able to test that a result is an email (myMail@provider.com ..)

I have tried to test if it's string using this :

```
$this->assertInternalType('string', $myExpectedEmail);
```

But I think it's not very accurate ... I tried this :

```
$this->assertInternalType('email', $myExpectedEmail);
```

But I get this error:

```
Type specified for PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsType <email> is not a valid type.
```

Any idea/best practice of how to test email format in PHPunit ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for validate an email address. Something like:

```
    $this->assertRegExp('/^.+\@\S+\.\S+$/', $myExpectedEmail);
```

hope this help

Answer (score 6):

If You want to check if result is the same email as expected (string comparison) You should use:

```
$this->assertSame($expectedEmailString, $emailToTest);
```

If You need to check if string is a valid email You can use:

```
$this->assertSame($emailToTest, filter_var($emailToTest, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Easy and clean solution
Enjoy :)

Comment: it's not working in case the email is in the correct format, I got back the email value.  

From documentaton : "Returns the filtered data, or FALSE if the filter fails. "

Error : Failed asserting that 'myEmail@gmail.com' is true.